# How can I monitor browser events in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, dom-events

I need to debug some differences in behaviour between browsers of (blur and focus) events in a web application I am working on.

In Chrome, I have been using the `monitorEvents` function. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality (logging events to the console) in IE (11)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following post has a link to a code snippet which mimics functionality similar to the `monitorEevents` function in Chrome:

https://coderwall.com/p/kc5pew/monitor-events-in-ie9-s-console

This was originally written for IE9, but I have used it with IE11 as well.

Comment: Can you also describe how to use it?